# my application created with wxPython crash Occasionally ，The event viewer shows that the location of the error is in wx\wxbase32u_vc140_x64.dll

Tags: python-3.x, windows, crash, wxpython

I use wxPython to develop a Windows application. When I compile it into exe and run it on the PC, the application will crash. After the crash, I check the Windows time viewer and the following information is displayed:

```
Faulting application name: Main.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x64cb546a
Faulting module name: wxbase32u_vc140_x64.dll, version: 3.2.2.1, timestamp: 0x64800e26
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Error offset: 0x000000000021afd0
Faulting Process ID: 0x3914
Faulting application startup time: 0x01d9c5df181e3b1a
Faulting Application Path: XXXXXX\Main.exe
Faulting module path: XXXXXX\wx\wxbase32u_vc140_x64.dll
Report ID: 5d7df594-b625-4057-91e8-b4173e42f676
Faulting package full name:
Faulting Package Relative Application ID:
When I run the source code in pycharm, a crash will also occur, and the running window does not give me any valid information, only a sentence Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)
```

I tried to use catch exception and output to local file, but nothing caught.

The occurrence of this kind of crash is completely random, and the probability is not high. Sometimes it only happens once in more than ten hours, and I have no clue at all.

```
wxPython version：4.2.1
Python version：3.8.5
```

I hope to find the root cause and fix this crash